# Hammer.js events prevent scrolling of horizontal website

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

[Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io) (v2.0.1) tap event works fine on horizontal scrolling websites, but prevents normal panning/scrolling of the content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because Hammer.js sets the `touch-action`-property to `pan-y`, which makes sense for vertically scrolling websites, but not for horizontal ones.

So, to solve this, add `touch-action: 'pan-x'` to your options variable, like this:

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(element, {
    touchAction: 'pan-x'
});
```

Hammer.js' wiki tipped me of: [Hammer.js Github wiki](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/How-to-fix-Chrome-35--and-IE10--scrolling-(touch-action))

And here is some information about `touch-action`: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx)